# Syntax to update column value based on values in related table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the two tables shown below. One `RailcarTrips` can have many `TripSegments`.

I want to set `RailcarTrips.Arrived` to true for all rows where there are no related `TripSegments` with `EndDate` set to NULL.

I don't know how to construct the WHERE clause.

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TripSegments](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RailcarTripId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [StartDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [EndDate] [datetime2](7) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TripSegments] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RailcarTrips](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DestinationCity] [nvarchar](80) NOT NULL,
    [DestinationState] [nvarchar](2) NOT NULL,
    [ReturnReleaseDate] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [PurchaseOrder] [nvarchar](80) NULL,
    [Arrived] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_RailcarTrips] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data, desired results and your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should return the rows you want to update:

```
SELECT *
FROM RailcarTrips RCT
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TripSegments TS WHERE TS.RailcarTripID = RCT.ID AND TS.EndDate IS NULL)
```

Then the update:

```
UPDATE RCT
SET Arrived = 1
FROM RailcarTrips RCT
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TripSegments TS WHERE TS.RailcarTripID = RCT.ID AND TS.EndDate IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you specified
Note, this query will update RailcarTrips to "arrived" even if there are no records in TripSegment for the given RailcarTrip

```
UPDATE RailcarTrips
SET Arrived = 'true'
WHERE Id in
(SELECT id FROM RailcarTrips r
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM TripSegment t
WHERE
t.RailcarTripId = r.Id
AND t.EndDate IS NULL
)
)
```

If you want to check for the existance of at least 1 TripSegment with EndDate, use this

```
UPDATE RailcarTrips
SET Arrived = 'true'
WHERE Id in
(SELECT id FROM RailcarTrips r
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM TripSegment t1
WHERE
t1.RailcarTripId = r.Id
AND t1.EndDate IS NULL
)
AND EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM TripSegment t2
WHERE
t2.RailcarTripId = r.Id
AND NOT t2.EndDate IS NULL) 
)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to set RailcarTrips.Arrived to true for all rows where there are no related TripSegments with EndDate set to NULL.
I'd test for (non)existence of child records first, and then turn that into an update query.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM RailCarTrips t
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM TripSegments ts WHERE ts.RailcarTripID = t.RailCarTripID WHERE EndDate IS NULL )
```